# CSS font weight not showing correctly

Tags: css

I have the following CSS code to make the font weight lighter and thinner i.e. less bold.

The font weight looks the same from 400 to 100.
How can I make the font weight look lighter/thinner?

```css
.fweight {
  border: 0px solid red;
  color: #90061a;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="fweight">Total Pledged Value</div>
```

Comment: The font you're using needs to support different numerical weights. Use a font that distinguishes between 100 and 400. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight?v=control

Comment: Unfortunately, you usually only have the option of `font-weight: normal` or `font-weight: bold`.

Comment: There are fonts that have more weights, for instance Google's Open Sans. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/5vm4njtm/).